# Using #define in an "if" statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

Is it possible to use `#define` in an "if" statement? The following code works, but I get a warning that the macro is being redefined.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
 #define TableViewHeight 916
 #define DisplayHeight 1024
 #define DisplayWidth 768
}
else {
 #define TableViewHeight 374
 #define DisplayHeight 480
 #define DisplayWidth 320
}
```

I also tried this, but it didn't work:

```
#ifdef UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
 #define TableViewHeight 916
 #define DisplayHeight 1024
 #define DisplayWidth 768
#else
 #define TableViewHeight 374
 #define DisplayHeight 480
 #define DisplayWidth 320
#endif
```

Any ideas?

Comment: IMO, this isn't what constants were built for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but it probably doesn't do what you think. Preprocessor directives are interpreted before the results of the preprocessing step are compiled.

This means that all of the preprocessor directives are interpreted, redefining some of the macros, before the remaining code, which will look something like below, is compiled.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
}
else {
}
```

In other words, after preprocessing, you just have empty `if` and `else` bodies.

If you want to change the value of something based on a condition at run time then that something will have to be an genuine object and not just a preprocessor macro. E.g.

```
extern int TableViewHeight; // defined somewhere else
extern int DisplayHeight; // defined somewhere else
extern int DisplayWidth; // defined somewhere else

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  TableViewHeight = 916;
  DisplayHeight = 1024;
  DisplayWidth = 768;
}
else {
  TableViewHeight = 374;
  DisplayHeight = 480;
  DisplayWidth = 320;
}
```

Comment: All four answers are factually correct, but this is the only one that actually explains the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` (and `#ifdef`, etc.) are processed by the preprocessor.  This runs entirely **before** the compiler itself; they are really two completely separate processes.  So it doesn't interact at all with constructs like `if`.

Your second code example might work, if `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` is a macro (i.e. it has been `#defined`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your own question :)  To remove the warnings, though, why not declare those as variables instead of macros?

I would do this:

```
CGFloat tableHeight = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 916.0f : 374.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

`#defines` are substituted by the preprocessor before the compiler runs. This means that you can't set their value at run time. The way I might do what you're going for is something like this:

In your .h file:

```
static CGFloat TableViewHeight;
static CGFloat DisplayHeight;
static CGFloat DisplayWidth;
```

in the .m file (class implementation):

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
     TableViewHeight = 916.0;
     DisplayHeight = 1024.0;
     DisplayWidth = 768.0;
    } else {
     TableViewHeight = 374.0;
     DisplayHeight = 480.0;
     DisplayWidth = 320.0;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
#define TableViewHeight ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 916.0 : 374.0)
#define DisplayHeight ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 1024.0 : 480.0)
#define DisplayWidth ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 768.0 : 320.0)
```

Finally, for DisplayHeight and DisplayWidth, you don't really need to do any of this and are probably better off using `CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds])` and `CGRectGetWidth([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds])`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `#if` instead of a normal `if`.

**However** that would be a preprocessor thing which would mean your application would simply only compile for either the iPhone or the iPad (if it even worked).

Bottom line: no, you cannot use macros. They are checked while compiling and not while running the application.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately. `#define` is used by the preprocessor to replace symbols before the code is compiled, while `if` is part of the actual code to be compiled. In the first case, the preprocessor knows nothing about what the result of your if statement will be.

The second case doesn't make sense because you don't care about whether `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`
is defined, you care whether `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` has that value.